# How to implement Validator with Filter in Restlet?

Tags: java, web-services, filter, validation, restlet

I am developing RESTLet webservices, for this I am using Restlet 2.0 API.

I want to implement Filter and Validator on webservices.

I have implemented Filter successfully. In the filter class I am checking that the request is authenticated means it is called from valid user. I am checking the header field to validate the request. This is my code -

```
public class MyFilter extends Filter {

@Override
    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
           // Conditions to check the header feild
        }
}
```

And my Application class is -

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

                Router router = new Router(getContext());

        Filter filter = new MyFilter(getContext());
        filter.setNext(MyWebservice.class);
        router.attach("/myWebservice", filter);

                return router;
         }
}
```

Now I want to implement Validator class to check that the **request** contains the required parameter. I want to follow the validator after the filter. But in application class we can provide either Filter or Validator. I am not getting any example to implement the validator with filter.

So please help me to implement Validator with Filter in restlet.

Answer (score 0):

It is set up to use the 'Chain Of Responsibility' Pattern - just try setting the Validator as 'Next' instead of the Resource class which then in turn has the resource set as next in it's chain.

Tweeked your code:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        Filter filter = new MyFilter(getContext());
        filter.setNext(new MyValidator(getContext(), MyWebservice.class));
        router.attach("/myWebservice", filter);

        return router;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this method and get back to you

Comment: check the bracketing I only give it one parameter.  the two parameters are taken by the Validator's constructor.  Alternativly the validator can be instanciated seperatly like you do for the Filter and validator.setNext(Service.class) used.